# Filling form automatically

Tags: database, ms-access

I do not know way which I can fill my form automatically. I mean that I made easy database which has just table. I made form too. User can write some information about herself/himself, for example name. If he/she end filling places to fill he/she should click send button and all information (expect ID - it gives admin) are on database. User can edit his/her information by clicking button - when he/she click it, it is possibility to write ID - when ID is ready, user can click button load data which fill all places by information connected with this ID.

I tried make some SQL query but it does not work. I past part of my code in window below, but I tried many combination of vba and sql - it always look very easy.

```
Private Sub button_wczytaj_Click()
OK_imie_wpr.Text = Select OK_imie from Karta_projektu where 
Numer_projekt_wpr = Numer_projekt
Form.Refresh
End Sub
```

`button_wczytaj` - button which load my data.

`OK_imie_wpr` - it is place where user can write his name - for example: `Tom
OK_imie` - it is place where i hold name on my table.

`Numer_projekt_wpr` - it is blocked place, user get his/her project ID from admin.

`Numer_projekt` - it is place where I hold ID on my table.

`Karta_projektu` - it is name of table.

I expect that when I fill place for ID and click load button I get all data connected with my ID. Something like:

```
SELECT OK_imie from Karta_projektu where ID = [And here i need id which user just write].
```

Comment: SELECT OK_imie from Karta_projektu where ID = " & Me.YourTextBoxName & "

Comment: @Tarun.P This way it is not work:

Private Sub Polecenie83_Click()
OK_imie_wpr.Value = SELECT OK_imie from Karta_projektu where Numer_projekt = " & Me.Numer_projekt_wpr & "
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select load Button Goto- Property- goto Event Propert- onlick Event-

'Assume your Textbox where you write your ID is Name as 'TxtID'

```
Dim Query1 as string

Query1 = "SELECT OK_imie from Karta_projektu where ID = " & Me.TxtID & " "

Me.Form.Recordsource = Query1
Me.Form.Requery
```

I hope you have created a Bound Form.

Comment: Why you use "Me.FORM" ? Can i make it to just one place? I mean can i use another name?

Me.NameOfMyPlace.Recordsource = Query1
Me.NameOfMyPlace.Requery

Comment: `Me.Form` refers to your Form from where your are executing your Vba.